# Can I say the phrase like this "In English I know for sure that this word means" or is it not natural to say it this way?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Is it grammatically correct to form a sentence like this?

> In English I know for sure that this word means ...

It differs from the 'textbook' way of saying the sentence, which would be

> I know for sure that in English this word means ...

So my question is can you say it this way? Does it sound right or I should better stick with textbook-like way of saying it?

Comment: _In English_ refers to the meaning and not to your knowledge, so your version is rather odd without punctuation. However, you could separate _I know for sure_ between commas, dashes or brackets. "In English, I know, this word means..."

Comment: @KateBunting "refers to the meaning and not to your knowledge"? For some reason I can't comprehend the meaning of this phrase neither by myself nor by using online translators. Could you explain what you meant?

Comment: I was trying to express that the sense of the sentence is _In English this means..._, and not  _In English I know_, so the 'textbook' version is more natural.

Comment: @KateBunting thank you! I think I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested example:

> (1) In English I know for sure that this word means ...

is not grammatically incorrect. It is, perhaps, a bit awkward. The suggestion by
Kate Bunting of:

> (2) In English, I know, this word means...

is better, I agree.

There is jo rule against starting with  the subject area, like "In English"